# Covergloobus On Loki

Tags: release-loki, music, spotify

Anyone tried using covergloobus on Loki?i have installed it.but it cant detect any player?Any suggestions guys?
I have tried installing .dev files.But It just not works.

Answer (score 1):

i use covergloobus in loki and work fine i install it from this deb files http://covergloobus.deviantart.com/  i hope to help you...